# World node output to compositing?

Tags: render-layers, world, compositing-nodes

I have an image as "World Environmental Equirectangular map".

I also have object meshes in separated Render layers.

How can I have the "World Environmental Equirectangular map" into the compositor so I can apply filter nodes to it, without affecting the other render layers?
(see attached image for better understanding)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DNR: You need to render a View Layer consisting of just the background.

Here's one way I know how to do this is

- Create your main scene with all of its collections but put the camera in a separate collection from everything else.   Here's a simple scene with a Suzanne:

[image: Simple scene with Suzanne]

- Optional: Give your main scene a name.  I called this main.
- Create a new *View Layer* by clicking on the new icon in the scene header:

[image: Adding a view layer]

- Give it a name.  I called mine "world only"
- Enable the 'only contributes indirectly' column: (t's the last one here.)

[image: selecting only contributes indirectly column]

- In the "world only" view layer click the indirectly box on all collections except the one with the camera:

[image: Enable only contribute indirectly]

- Render the scene.

Now you can add a *Render Layers* node in the compositor and set it to select the "world only layer.  Here's an example where I add a blur just to the background:

[image]

You may also want to add masks and other details to accomplish the effects you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion.
It did the trick.

Your suggestion is a real nice solution but I wouldn't mind if the developers could add this "World node output" option by default to the Render Layers node.

Again.. much appreciated.